# Отладка приложений на телефоне в Linux

Tags: android, eclipse, linux

Как отладить написанное в Eclipse приложение для Android на самом устройстве?
В Android Device Chooser подключенное устройство не определяется (точнее там просто вопросительные знаки).
ОС Debian Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте вот [эту](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) статью. Чтобы устройство определялось нужно вначале создать (под рутом) файл /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules (т.е. файл 51-android.rules в папке /etc/udev/rules.d). В нём вписать строку `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`, где вместо "0bb4" указать ID вашего производителя смартфона (см. таблицу по ссылке). После нужно будет указать права для созданного файла (`chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`) и может потребоваться перезагрузка adb.

Comment: У меня под Fedora спокойно все подхватывается. Проверял на куче девайсов (Nexus One, Galaxy S, Acer A500 и других).

Answer (score 1):

adb start-server сделайте от рута и телефон начнет удачно определяться эклипсом