# Отладка приложений на телефоне в Linux. IdVendor Fly

Tags: android

Всем привет. там описано как начать отладку приложений под разные телефоны и так же преведена таблицы idVendors: [Отладка приложений на телефоне в Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55661/android-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2-linux) , но дело в том что у меня телефон Fly iq 440 и в приведённой таблице я вендера не нашел. Подскажите пожалуйста может кто знает, какой vendor у fly???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

подключаете телефон, паралельно открываете консоль. Пишете там dmesg и смотрите на вывод. Там будет что то такое

```
[26331.110175] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[26331.122260] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee2
[26331.122264] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[26331.122266] usb 3-1: Product: Nexus 5
[26331.122267] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: LGE
[26331.122268] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 03501898d021a16b
```

собственно, вот для моего телефона  - `idVendor=18d1`.

Способ номер два. В консоли написать lsusb. В консоли будут перечислены все устройства, подключены к usb. Среди них не сложно найти свой телефон. У меня нужная строка выглядит так

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 5 (debug)
```

здесь vendor id прописан, но не указано, что это он.

Comment: Благодарю.